# jQuery DataTables: change focus after selecting rows-per-page dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, datatable, focus, rows

Working with jQuery DataTables, I'm using aLengthMenu to create a dropdown for selecting the number of rows per page. When the user makes a selection, the display changes properly, but focus remains on the dropdown -- so if a user selects from the dropdown and then hits the page down key (hoping to scroll down the page), the dropdown itself scrolls rather than the page. See http://esininja.com/Library.aspx.

Is there a way to create a row-selection dropdown that will move the focus away from the dropdown once a number of rows is selected? It's easy enough to simply click elsewhere on the page to remove focus from the dropdown, but not all users realize they need to, and it'd be nice if that were not necessary.

Many thanks.

Comment: Try to add a change event, and on change change the focus

Answer (score 0):

To have all select boxes lose focus when their value changes, this jQuery will do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/x9rxm/

```
    $(function() {
        $("select").change(function(){
            $(this).blur();
        });
    });
```

In your case, you could select the box you're thinking of with a more specific selector, possibly "[name=example_ESI_Articles_length]". Also, remember that this code will need to run after the 'select' element appears in the DOM.